# BluRay notebook drive spins up then down, doesn't mount

Tags: laptop, optical-drive, blu-ray

My blu-ray optical drive for my notebooks is acting funny. When I insert a blu-ray disc, it spins up some, then slows down and repeats. The disc never mounts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add some detail like make/model, Operating system? Are the disks OEM or burned?

Comment: they are oem pressed. the drive is an Optiarc BD ROM BC-5500S. Windows 7 x64.

Comment: What software do you use to play? OEM PowerDVD?

Comment: Its not a software issue. I can't even browse it in explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar issue when the player software is out of date and does not recognize a BluRay.  Is your softwre up to date?  Also have seen some OEMs that do not provide updates as often as the paid versions of same software.

Have seen comments that firmware can be an issue.  Check that but suspect player software.

Given the update above, is the hardware under warranty?  Have you contacted support for the drive?